# get_absolute_url id and slug in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, slug, absolute-path

*Hello, I want my URL be like this:*

**site.com/blog/books/details/[id]/[slug]**

*for example: **site.com/blog/books/details/3/blind_owl***

When I click on *Book's Name* Load Me Nothing. Even Doesn't Show An Error. I Want To Show Me **Description**

Thank you in Advance

**Model:**

```py
class Book(TimeStampMixin):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(to=Author, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    book_name = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.book_name)

class Details(TimeStampMixin):
    book = models.ForeignKey(to=Book, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:book_details', args=[self.pk, self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.book)
```

**The Main URL:**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

**URL:**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('authors/', views.authors, name='authors'),
    path('books/', views.books, name='books'),
    path('books/details/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', views.book_details, name='book_details')
```

**View:**

```py
def books(request):
    book = Book.objects.all()
    context = {'books': book}
    return render(request, 'Blog/books.html', context=context)

def book_details(request, pk, slug):
    details = Details.objects.filter(pk=pk, slug=slug)
    context = {'details': details}
    return render(request, 'Blog/book_details.html', context=context)
```

**Book Template:**

```
{% for each in books %}
<a href="{{ each.get_absolute_url }}">
    Book's Name: {{ each.book_name }}
</a>
{% endfor %}
```

**Book Details Template:**

```
{% for each in details %}
Description: {{ each.description }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in Book template you should put book name inside the `<a>` tag.
So

```
{% for each in books %}
<a href="{{ each.get_absolute_url }}">
    Book's Name: {{ each.book_name }}
</a> <!-- ended tag here -->
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class Details(TimeStampMixin):
...
  def get_absolute_url(self):
          return reverse('blog:book_details', kwargs={'id': self.id})
...
```

and templete

```
{% block content %}
    {% for obj in object_list %}
        <li>{{ forloop.counter }} - <a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}">{{ obj.title }}</a></li>
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```